# Window.confirm and html form

Tags: javascript, html

I have this form

```
<form name="frm" action="users.jsp/manage-users?status=delete&index=1" method="POST">
    <button value="delete" name="btn" onclick="if(window.confirm('Delete user?\nWARNING! THIS IS ACTION CANNOT BE UNDONE!'))
{document.frm.submit();}">
    Delete
    </button>
</form>
```

and when I press cancel, it still submits. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should really hook into the submit event, and this is how it should be done (preferably without inline JS, but anyway) -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/RvSLq/

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to `return false;`

```
<form name="frm" action="users.jsp/manage-users?status=delete&index=1" method="POST">
    <button value="delete" name="btn" onclick="if(window.confirm('Delete user?\nWARNING! THIS IS ACTION CANNOT BE UNDONE!'))
{document.frm.submit();}else{return false;}">
    Delete
    </button>
</form>
```

When you `return false;`, the form will not submit, so clicking `Cancel` will make the form not to submit, while clicking `Ok` will submit it

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qXJWL/

Comment: Thanks! It is working now. Never knew I had to add an else statement.

Comment: @ClydeSanchez - You don't, and you shouldn't!

Comment: @adeneo, whom are you commenting to? OP or me?

Answer (score 1):

Try `else { return false; }`

```
<form name="frm" action="users.jsp/manage-users?status=delete&index=1" method="POST">
    <button value="delete" name="btn" onclick="if(window.confirm('Delete user?\nWARNING! THIS IS ACTION CANNOT BE UNDONE!'))
{document.frm.submit();} else { return false; }">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

For good practice, make the script seperate from html, use `return false` when press cancel and use `return` with `formSubmit()`, something like

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function formSubmit(){
    if(window.confirm('Delete user?\nWARNING! THIS IS ACTION CANNOT BE UNDONE!')){
        document.frm.submit();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="frm" action="users.jsp/manage-users?status=delete&index=1" method="POST">
    <button value="delete" name="btn" onclick="return formSubmit()" id="myButton">
    Delete
    </button>
</form>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q3QRk/)